# AJP run out of thread

Tags: multithreading, apache, jboss5.x, ajp

I have the two apache load balance proxy servers(named A1, A2) run with mod_jk, and two Jboss web servers(named J1, J2).

Jboss version is jboss-eap-5.1.
   Apache version is 2.2.15.
   OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
   Both A1 and A2 colud redirect the request(with port 80) from outside to J1, J2(both are port 8080). The setting of A1,A2 are the same(except HostIP).  J1,J2 have the same setting too.(except HostIP and jvmRoute)

I have some problems with this architecture. J1 and J2 can process A1's request well(recive a request -> create a thread to process -> process finish -> close thread).

But A2's request is weird. When the process finished, the thread didn't closed. And network connection stay in ESTABLISHED.
  I used jstack PID to check, and there's a lot of following statements:

```
"ajp-XX.XX.72.12-8009-240" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f791418e800 nid=0x7793 runnable [0x00007f7875d5c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(AjpProcessor.java:1036)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.readMessage(AjpProcessor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:383)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`
```

Compared the above PID(nid=0x7793 ) with ps -efT | grep 30611 , can get the following:
    `xxxx 17869 30611 17821  0 20:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/java/bin/java -program.name=run.sh ...

And while I use netstat -A inet, there are lots of connection like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 npouiap2:8009               10.100.84.34:49666          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 npouiap2:8009               10.100.84.34:50374          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 npouiap2:8009               10.100.84.34:50507          ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be the threads aren't idle as **AJP connections** are persistent by default.

You can try some one of these options:

1. Increase `maxThreads` on JBoss to be the same as `"max threads"`
   (exact directives vary with MPM) on httpd
2. Turn on `mod_jk's` [disable reuse option](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/knowledge-base/jkoptions-disablereuse-benefits-over-standard-connection-pool-mechanism)

The option 2 is the simplest to apply and verify if the problem persist.

Comment: Hi Sierra,
    Thanks for your reply. The problems is that A1,A2 have the same setting, but only the connection from A2 would cause AJP thread hang on. I thought it may not cause by setting of maxThreads.
    And the option 2 seems to resolve the connection hang on problem on A1,A2. But the situation is that connections hang on J1,J2.

Comment: @nsnosheep You've tried stop the A1 server and only process requests with A2? Is there any message in the apache error log?

Comment: @Sierra I can't stop the A1 server. Cause it run on my company's production environment, and provide 7*24 services.

I ran tcpdump on J1 and J2. Find out that if request send from A1, J1 and J2 would get packages simultaneously(one got 11 packages and the other got 3 packages). If request send from A2, only one of J1 or J2 would got packages(14 packages).  
I look those packages, found out that packages from A2 have 3 SYN packages that did not send from A1.

Comment: @nsnosheep AJP is constant protocol. Once established the connections are never released but rather reused. Well unless you set the connectionTimeout which basically is not  "connection" timeout but rather the timeout between 2 http requests made over the persistent connection. For this I think A1 in some moment occupied all  threads from JBoss. You can try add disable reuse option y test if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi, Sierra.
I have thought about that. I will discuss with my colleagues who are in charge of Infra tomorrow.
But there's something weird. If A1 occupied all threads of JBoss, why I can still send request from A2 and got contents?
Thanks for your answer. :D

Comment: Hi, in this case may be only one J1 or J2 are full (or both), and depends on server take the connection is the result. Prove this is sometimes not an easy task and can be time consuming especially production environments.

Comment: Hi, @Federico Sierra I solved it. The threads of J1/J2 hang on because A1 or A2 is inactive and the connection cut off automatically(set up connection timed out in worker.properties). But J1/J2 do not set timed out. So that thread of J1/J2 think the connection is still established and can't get traffic any more.
While the new traffic come in, A1 or A2 will create new connection ( old one has cut off when connection timed out). Then we will see J1/J2 create new threads to process those new connection.

Comment: So, we should set up the same connection timed out term on Apache and Jboss while using connection pool then the threads will not hang on anymore.
Thanks for your help, Sincerely.